# How to De-Concatenate a Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a field in our SQL Server database that is basically two fields concatenated together.  It has a descriptor and a number.  I want to build a view with just the number so that I can relate it to other tables.  The number is actually typed as a nvarchar on the other tables.  So from data like this I want to query for just the number portion:

ProgramField with values:

```
tst_desc:1
tst_desc:124
tst_desc:1495
tst_desc:20483
```

So I'd like my query to return a result of:

ProgramNumField

```
1
124
1495
20483
```

The number is variable in length growing over time and needs to be nvarchar so I can relate it to the other tables in the database.

[image]

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: Perhaps you should fix the schema first so that it *doesn't* violate the 1NF - a field should containt only one value. In any case, what you are asking is splitting a string. In this case though, you can simply grab the characters from the semicolon's index to the end of the string

Comment: The result has to be right-justified?! How wide?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your prefix is always `tst_desc:` then you can simply strip it off with `replace`:

```
select
    replace(ProgramField, 'tst_desc:', '') as ProgramNum
from yourTable
```

If prefix can be different but always separated from value with colon, you can use something like:

```
select
    right(ProgramField, len(ProgramField) - charindex(':', ProgramField)) as ProgramNum
from yourTable
```

Comment: I would assume that 'tst_desc' is short for test description, which would probably have different values when using real data

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way is using STUFF

```
SELECT STUFF(ProgramField, 1, charindex(':', ProgramField), '')
FROM yourtable
```

If you have dirty data with more than one colon in some row or colon is missing, you can search from right to left for the first none numeric character, you could use this method, This can handle all sorts of funny data:

```
SELECT
  STUFF(RIGHT('@'+ProgramField, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',REVERSE(ProgramField)+'@')),1,1,'')
```

Comment: why is this "easier" than the `replace` solution?

Answer (score 1):

@Andy answer is correct, still you can check this answer.

```
Declare @t table(data varchar(50))
insert into @t values ('tst_desc:1'),  ('tst_desc:2'),  ('tst_desc:124'),  ('tst_desc:1495'),  ('tst_desc:20483')

select 
    Right( data, charindex (':',reverse(data))-1)
from @t
```